# Debian Testing - SNMPD Configuration for Zenoss

Tags: debian, snmp, zenoss, snmpd

```
Linux server1.xen.prgmr.com 3.0.0-1-686-pae #1 SMP Sat Aug 27 16:41:03 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
snmpd 5.4.3~dfsg-2.3
zenoss-stack 3.2.1-0
```

I have installed Debian Testing, Zenoss and smpd on the same server.  I am having a hell of a time trying to figure out where I am screwing up the snmpd config.  Zenoss sees the device, grabs the correct hostname and other values specified in snmpd.conf, yet I am unable to get any memory, cpu, load etc graphed.  They all display 'nan' -- Which Im assuming means I have something wrong.

If I model the device I do get some warnings like:

```
2011-10-21 08:39:44,898 WARNING zen.ZenModeler: Unable to get data for localhost from either ipAddrTable or ipNetToMediaTable
2011-10-21 08:39:44,902 WARNING zen.ZenModeler: No process information from hrSWRunEntry .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1
```

[/etc/default/snmpd](http://pastebin.com/NNfkg706) 
[/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/4sr5SiZu) 
[Zenoss Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL6v6.png)

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you using public as the community, or?

Comment: Yes, I am using public as the community.  My community in Zenoss is set to public and its defined in the config, so I think that part should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
```

Since you are connecting with the public commit you are limited to only the mibs define by systemonly.  You may want to remove the `-V systemonly` bit.

Comment: I also had to add this to the default file.  export MIBS=UCD-SNMP-MIB